# SQL Server 2008 : force user to change password at next login

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, security, logins

How can I force users to change their password at next login? I want all my user change their password at next login to choose new password with new policy.

`user must change password at next login` is disable and just can be enable for new logins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are creating a new login you have that option of " enforcing users to change the password at next login" from windows policies.
Therefore for To force a user to change password at next login, the sql login should be created with "`Enforce Password policy`" checked.

If you go back into this newly created login later, and look at the boxes, only 2 options are available to be checked. The “`User must change password at next login`” is grayed out.

> In order to access the box and force a password change, you need to
>   change the password. The reason is that if the account is compromised,
>   the hacker should not be the one to set a new password. The security
>   model assumes the administrator can contact the legitimate owner
>   offline and give them the new password.

You can refer [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0e034113-6e6a-406c-8514-a340e04d114d/how-to-prompt-a-user-to-change-his-sql-account-password?forum=sqlgetstarted) for same as well.

Comment: This seems to explain well the current behaviour. Still, the question was not "why can't I..." but "how can I...".